# Asterisk Win32 with .net workflow procedure

Tags: .net, interface, communication, asterisk

How to create communication between Asterisk and my .net application: for example

If user dial my asterisk gateway I would like to check his number and return some wave file.

when user dial "1" I would like to run some procedure on my app and return other wave file etc.

I Use http://www.asteriskwin32.com/

Is there any way to communicate with web services etc?

Comment: I found some information http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+FastAGI#NET

Answer (score 0):

You can extend your dialplan using [AGI](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+AGI). While my Asterisk work on Linux I use Python AGI library. I do similar thing you want to do: my AGI program connects to CRM WebService and checks if caller is known. Some callers (for example our staff) will hear other voice menu then "usual" callers.